# power series expansion in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, power-series

Let $p,q \in (0,1)$ sucht that $p + q = 1$. For $x_{1},x_{2} \in (-1,1)$ define the function $g(x_{1},x_{2})$ by
$$
g(x_{1},x_{2}) = \frac{qx_{1} + p^{2}x_{1}x_{2}}{1 - pqx_{1}x_{2}}. 
$$
Now $g$ is the generating function of some probability distribution $q(n_{1},n_{2})$ for $n_{1},n_{2} \geq 0$,i.e. 
$$
\sum_{n_{1},n_{2}=0}^{\infty}q(n_{1},n_{2})x_{1}^{n_{1}}x_{2}^{n_{2}} = g(x_{1},x_{2}).
$$
How can I expand $g$, so I can determine $q$.

Answer (score 0):

Since  the constraints that you give result into $$|pq x_1 x_2|<1$$
then you can apply the geometric series to the denominator and the expansion is simply
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {q\,x_1  + p^2 x_1 x_2 } \right)\sum\limits_{0 \le k} {\left( {pq\,x_1 x_2 } \right)^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0 \le k} {p^{\,k} q^{\,k + 1} \,x_1 ^{\,k + 1} x_2 ^{\,k}  + p^{\,k + 2} q^{\,k} \,x_1 ^{\,k + 1} x_2 ^{\,k + 1} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0 \le k} {\left( {p^{\,k} q^{\,k + 1} \,x_2 ^{\,k}  + p^{\,k + 2} q^{\,k} \,x_2 ^{\,k + 1} } \right)x_1 ^{\,k + 1} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0 \le n_1 } {\sum\limits_{0 \le n_2 } {c\left( {n_1 ,n_2 } \right)x_1 ^{\,n_{\,1} } x_2 ^{\,n_{\,2} } } }   \cr 
  & \quad \quad \quad  \Downarrow   \cr 
  & c\left( {n_1 ,n_2 } \right) = \left[ {1 \le n_1 } \right]\left( {\left[ {n_2  = n_1  - 1} \right]\left( {p^{\,n_1  - 1} q^{\,n_1 } } \right) + \left[ {n_2  = n_1 } \right]p^{\,n_1  + 1} q^{\,n_1  - 1} } \right) \cr} 
$$

where $[P]$ denotes the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)
$$
\left[ P \right] = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & {P = TRUE}  \\
   0 & {P = FALSE}  \\
 \end{array} } \right.
$$

Comment: The above function is the generating function of some probability distribution $q(n_{1},n_{2})$, i.e. $\sum_{n_{1},n_{2}=0}^{\infty}q(n_{1},n_{2})x_{1}^{n_{1}}x_{2}^{n_{2}} = g(x_{1},x_{2})$. So I want to expand it to determine $q(n_{1},n_{2})$. I think your answer does not make sense in my special situation

Comment: @love_math: I expanded the sum , hope now is clear what the coefficients of the double expansion will be.